# can anyone figure out how to get the appended element id to change value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

here is my attempt i am not being able to change values if there are more than one appended buttons please help me to the right path . i have a form on the right side which bring the values from the array object (at the end) and i want to change it so that change can update on my view and as well on the array object i have tried and this works but just for one button help required.

```js
if (ui.draggable.data('type') == "button") {
    btn_id++;
    $('#buttonDiv').css('display', 'block');
    $("<br><input type='submit' class='btn' id='btn-" + btn_id + "' value='My Button'>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this).click(function () {
        var value = $('#btn_value').val(button.button.value);

        $('#update').click(function () {
            if (button.button.id == $('#btn-' + btn_id + '').attr('id')) {
                button.button.value = $('#btn_value').val();
                value = $('#btn-' + btn_id + '').val($('#btn_value').val());
            } else {
                alert('oey');
            }
        });

        $("#btn_remove").click(function () {
            $('#btn-' + btn_id + '').remove();
            arr.splice(ui.draggable.data('type'), 1);
            $('#buttonDiv').css('display', 'none')
        });
    });

    var button = {
        button: {
            type: 'button',
            color: 'black',
            width: '15px',
            backgroundcolor: 'white',
            value: ' My Button',
            id: 'btn-' + btn_id + '',
            control: 'button',
            name: '',
            label: 'My Button',
            type: '',
            status: '',
            style: '',
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: '',

        }
    }
    var objectName = "button";
    arr.push(button);
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">Value:
    <br>
    <input id="btn_value" type="text" value="">
    <br>Update Component:
    <br>
    <input id="update" type="button" value="update" />
    <br>Remove Component:
    <br>
    <input id="btn_remove" type="button" value="remove" />
</div>
```

i hope anyone would guide me to the right path. if iam going in a wrong direction.

Comment: create a js fiddle to make it easier for us

Comment: Your snippet is no working because `ui is not defined`. Maybe is better if you publish in a jsfiddle.net and include jquery and jquery-ui to see it working

Comment: i dont know much about jsfiddle :(

Comment: i need to update the value of the appended button and update should be on array of objects as well as on the appended element value@MarcosPérezGude @thariama

Comment: jsfiddle works like this: you copy your code. You paste in the jsfiddle propper sections. you select external libraries (if there are). You click on save and the url share with us. Thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5hc82cak/1/ here it is i tried but not working if you can make it work @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: I don't know what are you attempting to make. I don't understand you. jsFiddle is working but you need something more: http://jsfiddle.net/5hc82cak/2/ (note that I included jquery-ui)

Comment: the value field should be updating array of object and the appended element attributes i hope you can get this